# ubuntu route all client eth0 traffic to openvpn on client tun0

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, bridge, nic

OpenVPN client has 2 physical interfaces:

```
eth0 = 192.168.10.14/24 gw 192.168.10.1
eth1 = 192.168.10.17/24 gw 192.168.10.1
tun0 = 172.160.1.6/24 gw 172.16.1.5
```

Server is external somewhere listening on 172.16.1.1 and has `ip_forwarding` enabled and is already setup for POSTROUTING with iptables.

eth1 needs to be able to continue to talk to the internal LAN, but eth0 needs to be able to route all traffic through the VPN.

I have so far been unable to find the correct combination of ip route, route add, changing gateways, and iptables rules, but there must be a way.

If an OpenVPN bridge is the correct answer, then I'm okay with that except that I've never been able to set one up correctly.  Tunnels are what I'm better at with OpenVPN.

Is it possible to bridge the tun0 and eth0 interface maybe?  I was unsuccessful, but if someone knows a workaround?

Comment: bridge operates at layer 2 and i think tun devices does not http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/75-general/305-what-is-the-difference-between-a-tun-device-and-a-tap-device.html, i did a bridge between eth0 and tap0 without problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough detail about what you're trying to achieve or your network setup for me to be able to give a detailed answer.

If you want to bridge two networks your OpenVPN instance needs to create a tap interface, not a tun.  You can then use the standard linux brctl utility to bridge eth0 and tap0 (or whatever interface name you choose).

You might find it easier to stick to a routed connection though, in which case you need to come up with an addressing plan for the whole network and ensure the gateways on each of your LANs are aware (using static routes is best in a simple two-office setup) of the VPN routers as a way to get to the other networks.